# AttributeError: 'Str' Object Has No Attribute 'Mean_validation_score' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

This error occurs in my code: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean_validation_score'. What can I do to resolve it?

```
GridMean = [result.mean_validation_score for result in 
gridA.cv_results_]
print(GridMean)
plt.plot(k_values, GridMean)
plt.xlabel('Value of "K" for KNN')
plt.ylabel('CrossValidated Accuracy')
```

Comment: Obviously the result object is of type string and a string object doesn't have `mean_validation_score` attribute. The code, relevant to fixing this issue is before the part you provided.

Answer (score 1):

"mean_validation_score" is depricated now it's "mean_test_score". Use "mean_test_score".

For your confirmation you can check-it-out

```
gridA.cv_results_.keys()
```

After running the above comment you can see there is no "mean_validation_score".

Answer (score -1):

I presume you are working with `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`, with `gridA` being an instance of `GridSearchCV`.

I am not sure when the method `mean_validation_score` was deprecated for `GridSearchCV` objects, but for sklearn 0.22 you can get the scores calling them with the key `'mean_test_score'` being `gridA.cv_results` a dictionary. Like this:

`GridMean = gridA.cv_results_['mean_test_score']`